# python lists: merge and replace

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a more elegant/Pythonic way of doing the following task:

I have two string lists `A` and `B`, where `B` is almost a subset of `A` except that `B` has a postfix `*` for some of the elements. My goal is to replace elements in `A` with those corresponding elements in `B` that have the postfix. An example:

```
A = ['abcd', 'ddse', '123d', 'aaaaa']
B = ['ddse', 'aaaaa*']
```

I'd like to get a list as `['abcd', 'ddse', '123d', 'aaaaa*']`. The way I can think of is to split and transform `A` in to a two-column dataframe and merge with `B`, then put the `*` column back to column in `B`. But that does not look very elegant since I need to do a lot of this operation. Is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `*` is always at the end, it's pretty simple with this code:

```
C = [(x + '*') if ((x + '*') in B) else x for x in A]
```

To do the same thing for a list of lists, try this; you will get the results in a list of lists C then:

```
C = []
for A, B in zip(A_L, B_L):
    C.append([x + '*' if ((x + '*') in B) else x for x in A])
```

Comment: Thanks! This works nicely. One more question, what if `A` and `B` are lists of lists? That is, the `A`, `B` in my example are actually one element of the two lists `A_L` and `B_L` that I want to merge. I want to do a element-wise merge on `A_L` and `B_L`. How to nest your code into this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you just need to replace `B` and `A` with the respective list. Therefore, when I understand you right, just replace `B` with `B_L[0]` and `A` with `A_L[0]`

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. So to do the element-wise merge, I need to loop through the index for `A_L` and `B_L`? Can I nest this loop inside the list comprehension as well?

Comment: Thanks! I just tried list comprehension it also works: `[[(x + '*') if ((x + '*') in B_L[i]) else x for x in A_L[i]] for i in range(0, len(A_L))]`. I think it is faster though I haven't test it yet.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?:

```
def doit(A,B):
    for n,i in enumerate(A):
        if i + '*' in B:
            A[n] = i + '*'
```

Comment: Yeah, this is totally functional.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I really don't see why you think Juan's code is incorrect. His output is correct, and his answer's code is functionally identical to that of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
[ e+'*' if e+'*' in B else e for e in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you really want to check, for every element `a` of `A`, whether there is some element `a*` of `B`, and if there is some `a*`, to replace `a` in `A` with `a*`.

```
#make a copy of A with * appended to every element
C = [a + "*" for a in A]
#loop through C and check 
for i in range(len(A)):
    if C[i] in B:
        A[i] = C[i]
```

Comment: It does not add * to every element. I have tested my code. Please verify its integrity by running it.

Comment: You have OBVIOUSLY not tried running my code. It works for the example given, as well as for your example on Juan Cespedes' answer.

Comment: I may note that this code is almost functionally identical to the answers upvoted thus far.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You're online, and you haven't undone your downvote. Please explain to me exactly what you think is wrong with my code.

Comment: This is a non-pythonic way and pretty inefficient, but it works for me.